# How does google assistant interacts with dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am calculating the price to use dialogflow and found out the price for voice input in dialogflow scales quickly to be very expensive with a lot of users.

Does google assistant translate voice input into text before sending to dialogflow for process?

**Edit***
Emailed Dialogflow support and got confirmation that request coming from Google Assistant integration will be counted as text and exempted from any charges for Dialogflow Standard Edition.

Comment: If you create your first Assistant bot, you will get $200 per month for 12 months as credit from Google. It may help in some of the cost that you are concerned of.

Comment: If you like it or helped you, you may upvote it :)

Answer (score 0):

Google assistant will send your input voice to the Dialogflow(if dialogflow is enabled in action on google console), And From the Dialogflow, the response is naturally parsed through NLP engine of Dialogflow.

Google assistant will use only its speech to text conversation and send it to Dialogflow.